# If you're saving Java Exception information in the DB, what parts of the Exception should you save to help figure out the problem without redundancy?

Tags: java, exception

Which parts of the `java.lang.Exception` object need to be saved in the database to give you the best chance of recreating the problem that led to the Exception being thrown?

And which parts, if saved together, would create redundant information?

For example, if you save the result of calling `exception.getMessage()`, and you also save `exception.getCause().getMessage()`, will you end up with duplicate information?

And, if you save `exception.getMessage`, would it be redundant to also save the output from `exception.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Why save it in the database?  Why not just log it out and save your log file(s)?  That will preserve more context about the error than just storing the Exception will.  Also, some logging frameworks can be configured with a database appender, so you could still store information in a database if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

My strategy would be to save a timestamp and the stack trace of the exception.

That is the most important thing that is needed to try to diagnose the problem that provoked the exception.

Comment: so for sql we can only fit 65k chars in a row. If we save the entire stack trace, dont you think there could be times where were pushing this limit?

Answer (score 1):

Saving error data in the database usually only serves the purpose of further analysis of such data. From that standpoint, I recommend you have certain classification for your own exceptions. For example, assign them some error code. Some specific error code should be dedicated to unknown exceptions. Now, you save to database the error code and (preferably in separate column) a message from exception. For unknown exceptions, I would consider calling `toString()` that would include exception class and the message. Stack trace better belongs to log. But to have easier time locating it, include some information such as request id in database that would allow to easily search log for that stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save:

- stack trace
- message
- timestamp

The printStackTrace is redundant to getMessage. Look at the code:

```
    public void printStackTrace(PrintWriter s) {
    synchronized (s) {
        s.println(this);
        StackTraceElement[] trace = getOurStackTrace();
        for (int i=0; i < trace.length; i++)
            s.println("\tat " + trace[i]);

        Throwable ourCause = getCause();
        if (ourCause != null)
            ourCause.printStackTraceAsCause(s, trace);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String s = getClass().getName();
    String message = getLocalizedMessage();
    return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why the exceptions need to be in a database? Couldn't they be logged as part of the application log files? log4j loggers have nice pretty prints of exceptions that include the full stack trace, cause, timestamp, ...etc. That maybe all you need.